# What does the + operator do in cout?

Tags: c++, iostream

In the following code I got confused and added a + where it should be <<

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    char someLetter = aLetter(true);
    cout <<"Still good"<<endl;
    cout << "someLetter: " + someLetter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Should be

```
cout << "someLetter: " << someLetter << endl;
```

The incorrect code outputted:

> Hello world!
>   Still good
>   os::clear

What I don't understand is why the compiler didn't catch any errors and what does os::clear mean? Also why wasn't "someLetter: " at the start of the line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, `"someLetter: "` is a string literal, i.e. a `const char *` pointer, usually pointing to a read-only area of memory where all the string literals are stored.

`someLetter` is a `char`, so `"someLetter: " + someLetter` performs pointer arithmetic and adds the value of `someLetter` to the address stored in the pointer. The end result is a pointer that points somewhere past the string literal you intended to print.

In your case, it seems the pointer ends up in the symbol table and pointing to the second character of the name of the `ios::clear` method. This is completely arbitrary though, the pointer might end up pointing to another (possibly inaccessible) location, depending on the value of `someLetter` and the content of the string literal storage area. In summary, this behavior is undefined, you cannot rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operator has nothing to do with `cout`.

As seen in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) table, `+` has higher precedence than `<<`, so the offending line of code gets parsed as follows:

```
(cout << ("someLetter: " + someLetter)) << endl;
```

In other words, `+` is applied to a char pointer and a char. A char is an integral data type, so you are really performing pointer arithmetics, adding the integer value of the char on the right-hand side to the pointer on the left-hand side, producing a new char pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the C string `"someLetter: "` is using the `char someLetter` as an index, and therefore  pointing to some part of memory. Hence the behaviour.

In C++ if you do silly things you get strange behaviour. The language gives you plenty of rope to hang yourself with.

Answer (score 2):

The + is doing pointer arithmatic on `"someLetter: "`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that literal string are just pointers to some memory area. What `"someLetter: " + someLetter` does is adding a value to that pointer and then trying to print that.

Comment: I can't remeber that literal strings are just pointers because I never learned that :-) How does that work?

Comment: String literals are **not** pointers. They're arrays of const chars. As such, they behave like any array, and may sometimes decay to a pointer to their first element.